# SQL: Return row(s) based on pairs of cells with common values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a social media like database where users can follow each other, and users can also have interests. 
I would like to know how I can return the row(s) that list the users who are following each other and who have at least one interest in common.

I have written the query to display the users who follow each other, and what the user who is being followed is interested in. I need to isolate the pairs of users who follow each other and are interested in the same thing.

CODE SO FAR:

```
SELECT me.followed, me.following, me.interest FROM 
    (SELECT followed, following, interest
    FROM follow JOIN interest
    WHERE followed = interest.user_id
    ORDER BY followed) AS me
INNER JOIN follow AS you ON me.following = you.followed
WHERE me.followed = you.following
```

[table] https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Xtt.png

```
 A   B C 
 2   1 2 
 2   1 6 
 2   1 9 
 1   2 1 
 1   2 7 
 1   2 8 
 7  15 1 
 7  15 7 
 15  7 2
 15  7 7
```

(A = followed, B = following, C = user interest)
Sorry for the formatting, there seems to be no simple way to make tables.

My table so far shows that user 2 follows user 1, and user 1 follows user 2. Same for users 15 and 7. It also shows user 2 is interested in interest 2, interest 6, and interest 9.

I want to write some code that should just return user 7 and user 15, as they are the only users that follow each other and have a common interest (interest 7), but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Please post data as text, not images. It will make it a lot easier for people to (a) read and (b) answer your question.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted your code. An aside, these types of questions are best answered by graph algorithms/databases. You might look at options like Neo4J or a similar database for answering these questions.

Comment: Just use code blocks and space-formatted tabular representation. We use services like sqlfiddle.com that ca parse it into a table when testing queries. Even better, you can use them to generate the DDL/DML statements necessary to set up a test case; either post the statements here or post a link to the relevant fiddle site after you've set up the test data and saved the fiddle. google for **DB fiddle** for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another join to `user_interest`:

```
SELECT me.followed_user_id, me.following_user_id, 
   me.interest_id AS 'same interest id'
FROM user_follow AS me
JOIN user_follow AS you -- me and you follow each other
  ON me.following_user_id = you.followed_user_id
 AND me.followed_user_id = you.following_user_id
JOIN user_interest AS me_int -- my interest
ON me.following_user_id = me_int.user_id
JOIN user_interest AS you_int -- your interest
  ON me.followed_user_id = you_int.user_id
 AND me_int.interest_id = you_int.interest_id --must be the same
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't knwo if I've misunderstood, but can this query be answered by just the user_follow table?

```
SELECT * FROM
  user_follow a 
  INNER JOIN 
  user_follow b
  ON
    a.followed_user_id = b.following_user_id AND
    a.following_user_id = b.followed_user_id AND
    a.interest_id = b.interest_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing this query, I would want a result set where pairs of users only appear once and there is a count of interests in common.

So:

```
select uf.followed_user_id, uf.following_user_id,
       count(*) as interests_in_common
from user_follow uf join
     user_interest uifed
     on uifed.user_id = uf.followed_user_id join
     user_interest uifing
     on uifing.user_id = uf.followed_user_id and
        uifing.interest_id = uifed.interest_id
where (uf.followed_user_id, uf.following_user_id) in
          (select uf2.following_user_id, uf2.followed_user_id
           from user_follow uf2
          ) and
      uf.followed_user_id < uf.following_user_id
group by uf.followed_user_id, uf.following_user_id;
```